# Set Cookie with PHP Check with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

Create Cookie in PHP and Check it with Jquery

I'm trying to create a cookie in PHP

```
$cookie_name = "timein";
$cookie_value = $id;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400), "/");
```

Then check to see if it's there (after a page refresh, for instance) in an if statement with Jquery

```
if ($.cookie("$cookie_name")) {
    $("#clockinbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
};.
```

I installed the jquery.cookie plugin but I'm not sure how to get the coding right or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the bad name for the cookie you are looking at.

Actually, your js code will look at a cookie named "$cookie_name", which is not what you want. You want to get the cookie named "timein".

Use:

```
$.cookie('timein');
```

If you want to check all the available cookies, just call:

```
$.cookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be more likely:

```
if ($.cookie("timein")) {
    $("#clockinbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
};
```

Be sure to use the REAL name of cookie in this case it's `timein`